# Highlight invalid field when ConstraintValidator fails

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bean-validation

I want to ensure that only date values between 1.1.1900 and 31.12.2100 are entered via WebUI. Therefore I created the `@Date` annotation and the corresponding validator implementation `DateValidator.java`.

In my entity class the date field is annotated with `@Date`. Whenever I enter an invalid date value, the default message from the `@Date` annotation is shown in the global `<p:messages .../>` but the input field is not marked as invalid, as this is done when an empty value is entered!

When I enter an empty value, the @NotNull validation fails in the `PROCESS_VALIDATION` phase, the error message is shown, the input field is highlighted and the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase is executed next.

In case of an invalid date value,  the error message is shown but also `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES`, `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` and `RENDER_RESPONSE` are executed!

Date.java

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {DateValidator.class})
@Documented
public @interface Date {
    String message() default "Invalid Date";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List {
        Date[] value();
    }
}
```

DateValidator.java

```
public class DateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Date, Calendar> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Date date) {}

    /**
     * Returns {@code true}, if Date of Calendar is between 1.1.1900 and 31.12.2100
     *
     * @param calendar
     * @param constraintValidatorContext
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Calendar calendar, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (Optional.ofNullable(calendar).isPresent()) {
            if (calendar.compareTo(minDate) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (calendar.compareTo(maxDate) == 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Calendar minDate = new GregorianCalendar(1900, 0, 1);
    private static Calendar maxDate = new GregorianCalendar(2100, 11, 31);
}
```

Entity.java

```
public class Entity {
    private java.util.Calendar date;

    @NotNull
    @Date
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = MisEntity.DATETIME_PATTERN)
    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    public java.util.Calendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }   
}
```

page.xhtml

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showDetail="true"/>

<p:outputLabel for="date" ="#{bundle['date']}"/>
<p:calendar id="date" showButtonPanel="true" showOn="button"
            required="true"
            value="#{bean.date}"
            mask="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"> 
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{component.pattern}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

When I implement a `FacesValidator` and use this validator for the input field, the validation fails on invalid values in `PROCESS_VALIDATIONS`, 
the error message is shown, the invalid field is highlighted and `RENDER_RESPONSE` is the next phase.

DateValidator2.java

```
@FacesValidator("my.company.web.validation.DateValidator")
public class DateValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        boolean valid = false;
        if (Optional.ofNullable(value).isPresent() && value instanceof Date) {
            Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime((Date) value);
            valid = calendar.compareTo(minDate) != -1 && calendar.compareTo(maxDate) != 1;
        }
        if (!valid) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Invalid date");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }

    private static Calendar minDate = new GregorianCalendar(1900, 0, 1);
    private static Calendar maxDate = new GregorianCalendar(2100, 11, 31);
```

}

page2.xhtml

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showDetail="true"/>

<p:outputLabel for="date" ="#{bundle['date']}"/>
<p:calendar id="date" showButtonPanel="true" showOn="button"
            required="true"
            value="#{bean.date}"
            mask="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"> 
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{component.pattern}"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="my.company.web.validation.DateValidator"/>
</p:calendar>
```

So the question is, how to use a `ConstraintValidator` that also highlights invalid input fields - it should be possible, because `@NotNull` does it as expected!

I have a big domain model where I want to annotate each `Calendar` field with `@Date` and I do not want to add for each input field the validator using `<f:validator validatorId=".."/>`

Comment: How does it work with a plain jsf `h:inputText` (where you enter the correct date format). The reason I ask is to narrow down if it is PrimeFaces related or not

Comment: Using `<h:inputText id="date" value="#{bean.date}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                            </h:inputText>` results in the same behavior! Error message shown, invalid field not highlighted, PROCESS_VALIDATION not failed!

Comment: @Kukeltje: do you have any findings about the subject?